# How to extract key value for a particular key stored in csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, key-value

I have a csv file which has 3 columns. One of the column has data in the form of key value.

Example (source, Topic and Views are columns)

```
Source        Topic                                                       Views

Web        {"title":"Weather for Paris 
            ","object":"storm,hail","description":"thunderstorm"}          234
```

Here the column Topic has values in the form of key value. keys here are title, object and description. I just want to extract the value under the key 'title' for all the records in the csv.

Expected output

```
Weather for Paris
```

How to accomplish this using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pandas.read_csv('dict.csv', usecols = ['Topic'], sep = '|')
df['Topic'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)['title']).values
```

where `dict.csv` has the structure

```
Source|Topic|Views
Web|{"title":"Weather for Paris","object":"storm,hail","description":"thunderstorm"}|34
```

Note that I added the separator `|`, otherwise the dictionary will not properly parse. Another option is to have something like

```
Source,Topic,Views
Web,"{""title"":""Weather for Paris"",""object"":""storm,hail"",""description"":""thunderstorm""}",34
```

In this case you only need to drop the `sep` option from the call to `read_csv`

Comment: Thanks for you solution @caverac.